# Apache Thrift. Method returning type changed after generation

Tags: java, hadoop, thrift

I got an issue after regeneration my thrift file. Method returning type changed in getter and setter after generation, but structs weren't changed.

```
> struct Descriptor {
> 1: bool   paramOne,      
> 2: i32    paramTwo,       
> }
```

before:

```
> public void setParamTwo(List<String> paramTwo) {
>   ......
>  }
```

after:

```
> public Descriptor setParamTwo(List<String> paramTwo) {
>    ......
> }
```

I used

> thrift -r --gen java file.thrift

There are some options for configuring it?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean `thrift -r -gen java file.thrift`?

Comment: @JensG Thanks.
I just forgot added java. But the question was in returning type of setters, which by default generating as Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.

Just need to add :beans in gen command

> thrift -r --gen java:beans file.thrift